# ImportError: No module named postgresql, Already installed psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, python-module

For installing OpenGnSys, we need to run script which then calls python script. This python script gives following error:

```
[root@custrohitkr opengnsys2-web]# ./db.py 
postgresql://opengnsys:opengnsys@localhost/opengnsys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./db.py", line 88, in <module>
    create()
  File "./db.py", line 81, in create
    db = create_engine(database, echo=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 223, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 48, in create
    dialect_cls = u.get_dialect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 91, in get_dialect
    module = getattr(__import__('sqlalchemy.databases.%s' % self.drivername).databases, self.drivername)
ImportError: No module named postgresql
```

After searching on net I found that module `psycopg2` should be installed for `postgesql`. But in my case it is already there. What may be the issue?

Comment: Can you post here a pip freeze?

Comment: Do you use virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

[Are we talking about a misconfiguration of the url](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html)

```
postgresql://opengnsys:opengnsys@localhost/opengnsys
```

vs

```
postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@localhost/mydatabase
```

Comment: Googling the same error, brought me to here, only to realize that we moved from pypostgresql to psycopg2 and I forgot to modify the db url. So I guess your answer is the correct one. At least in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

try specifying a port number, ie 3306